# Possibility to select specific input fields javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I will show you guys what I got with jsfiddles because it makes it easier to explain.
This is what kind of form setup im running right now. (Just showing you some fields, not all)

http://jsfiddle.net/XK99Z/2/

When you change the number in one of the input fields the price will immediately change too.
It uses this piece of JS for that:

```
function changeTotalFromCount(input) {
    var unitPrice = parseFloat(input.getAttribute("data-unitPrice"));
    var count = input.value;

    var price = unitPrice * count;
    var formattedPrice = '\u20ac ' + price.toFixed(2);

    var label = input.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    label.innerHTML = '';
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formattedPrice));
}
```

When they press the submit button they will be taken to another page where the order is with their personal details, a print button and a change order button. If they press the change order button they will go back to the page like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KPfUT/

And as you can see the price won't show next to the number anymore, but someone helped me find a solution for this problem:

```
function initTotals() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        changeTotalFromCount(inputs[i]);
    }
}
window.onload = initTotals;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7LKf7/2/

Now there is one problem, it won't work together with other input fields, like name, phone number, adres, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/Af724/1/

I was hoping someone could help me find a solution to this maybe let JS know i only want it to run for `input type="number"` since all the personal details input fields are text.

I'm nowhere near experienced in JS so please let me know if you don't understand my question or you need some more information, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` to only select the type="number" input elements:

```
var numberInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
for (var i = 0; i < numberInputs.length; i++) {
    changeTotalFromCount(numberInputs[i]);
}
```

or check the elements for their type:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'number')
        changeTotalFromCount(inputs[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! This works exactly as I wanted to, i appreciate the effort you took to help me.